# Truncate mediawiki

Tags: mysql, api, mediawiki, wikipedia

I'm working with the mediawiki API ( e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php) and I would like to be able to 'truncate' the mysql tables in order to reset the local installation while keeping some tables (users, ?...).
What would be the SQL queries ?

I would say: tuncate all the tables but ${PREFIX}_user and  update ${PREFIX}_user set user_editcount=0 ?

Any other(safer) suggestion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer was posted on the MediaWiki mailing list: see http://lists.wikimedia.org/pipermail/mediawiki-l/2009-October/032322.html

According to that post, it is probably ok to truncate `user_newtalk`, `page`, `revision`, `text`,
`archive`, `pagelinks`, `templatelinks`, `imagelinks`, `categorylinks`, `category`, `externallinks`, `langlinks`, `hitcounter`, `watchlist`, `image`, `oldimage`, `filearchive`, `recentchanges`, `searchindex`, `interwiki`, `querycache`, `objectcache`, `log_search`, `trackbacks`, `job`, `querycache_info`, `redirect`, `querycachetwo`, `page_restrictions`, `protected_titles`, `page_props`, `change_tags`, `tag_summary`, `valid_tag`, `l10n_cache`.

On more recent versions, add `msg_resource` and `msg_resource_list` to that list, to [truncate message related caches](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Moving_a_wiki#Frequent_problems).

Also: Remember to delete the files at the image folder, if truncating the
image table. Otherwise they will be out of sync, and you might have trouble uploading some images.

Answer (score 0):

get list of tables from your database:

```
echo "show tables;" | mysql -u user_name -p db_name > tables
```

determine which tables you want to truncate, then create an sql script

```
TRUNCATE TABLE a;
TRUNCATE TABLE b;
update <prefix>user set user_editcount=0;
```

then run it through the client:

```
mysql -u user_name -p database_name < truncate-all.sql
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't tell me *which* tables of mediawiki should be truncated.